# Rows in LazyVGrid shift up when content changes

Tags: swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI and have been prototyping a card matching game. At the moment, I am just setting up the grids and the face up/down toggling. In this example, I have the preview set to run on an iPhone 14 and it'll have two rows with the top row being cards a-e and the bottom row with just f. When I click on card "a", it flips correctly but the whole second row shifts up. My guess is that the content of that card is being removed, causing it to compress a little bit but I can't figure out why that would happen. Is there a way to "fix" either the card content or the LazyVGrid rows so that the rows don't shift up or down?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var emojis = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
    var emojiCount = 6
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 65))]){
                    ForEach(emojis[0..<emojiCount], id: \.self) { emoji in
                        CardView(content: emoji).aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                        
                    }
                }.foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
struct CardView: View {
    var content: String
    @State  var isFaceUp: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            if isFaceUp{
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
                Text(content)
            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}


 
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.light)

        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to fix the card content.  Include the `Text(content)` in the face down `View`, but add `.opacity(0)` to make it invisible:

```
struct CardView: View {
    var content: String
    @State  var isFaceUp: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            if isFaceUp{
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
                Text(content)
            } else {
                shape.fill()
                Text(content).opacity(0)  // here
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Alternate Solution:

Make the `Text(content)` an `.overlay` of the card.  That way it won't change the size of the `CardView`:

```
if isFaceUp{
    shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
    shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
        .overlay {
            Text(content)
        }
} else {
    shape.fill()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Both of these solutions work!

Comment: Do you know why this is necessary?